# The comparison of adjectives

Tags: grammar

My friend's grades are twice as high as mine.
My friend's grades are twice higher than mine.

What is the difference between them or which one is more suitable to use

Comment: Related: [Do “twice as high xxxxx as” , “twice as high” and “twice higher” mean the same thing?](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/30883/do-twice-as-high-xxxxx-as-twice-as-high-and-twice-higher-mean-the-same-t)

Comment: Sorry, what is the grading SCALE being used? It would not be common in English-speaking countries to be saying this: scales of 20 or 100 are not usually used for grades....just saying.

Answer (score -1):

It is more suitable to say My friend's grades are twice as high as mine.
To phrase it the other way you might say My friend's grades are two times higher than mine.

Answer (score -1):

There is a difference between the two: "twice as high as mine" compares the grades of your friend to your own, whereas "twice higher than mine" would seem to express frequency, that your friends grades have been higher than yours on two occasions.

Please note that this expression of frequency is usually clarified by conjugating the verb in the present perfect tense, so as to make a present statement while referring to past events: "My friends grades have twice been higher than mine."